# appending list in python with things not already in it

Tags: python-2.7

Apologies if this has been answered but I didn't see the answer anywhere. I have a text file containing a column with the same set of strings multiple times and I want a list which just contains the each unique string.

For example the set of strings (from a txt file, not already in a list):

one, one, one, two, two, three, three, three, three

would become:

["one", "two", "three"]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
lst = "one, one, one, two, two, three, three, three, three".split(", ")
unique_set = set(lst)
```

This creates the set (sets are not ordered):

```
{'three', 'one', 'two'}
```

Comment: @EuanRitchie no problem, take a look at the manual and read about the basic functionality. It's very helpful.